# Python set constructor syntax

Tags: python

Does anyone know the justification for this confusing set construction syntax? I spent a day unable to find this bug because I missed a comma in constructing a set.

```
> {1 2} 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  # This makes sense.
> {'a' 'b'} = set(['ab'])    # This does not.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with sets.

Two string literals separated by whitespace are considered *one* string literal.

```
rationale = ('This is quite useful when you need to construct '
             'a long literal without useless "+" and without '
             'the indentation and newlines which triple-quotes bring.')
```

Answer (score 6):

That's not a set construction syntax thing. You're running into implicit string literal concatenation, a confusing and surprising corner of the language:

```
>>> 'a' 'b'
'ab'
```

If you write two string literals next to each other, they're implicitly combined into one string. (This only works with literals; `str(3) str([])` is a syntax error, not `'3[]'`.)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean

```
>>> {'a' 'b'} == set(['ab']) 
True
```

?

That's just because 2 strings are concatenated to 1 string:

```
>>> type('a' 'b')
<class 'str'>
>>> len('a' 'b')
2
>>> print('a' 'b')
ab
```